# Get transform and scaled coordinates after manupilation with image data

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to learn how to scale a canvas. i.e. make it panable and zoomable

```
// viewport canvas
let canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

To do this, I create a second canvas:

```
// new canvas with image_data
let new_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
new_canvas.width = 500;
new_canvas.height = 500;
let new_canvas_ctx = new_canvas.getContext('2d');
```

After that I create an ImageData object and fill it with data:

```
let image_data_canvas = ctx.createImageData(500,500);

// fill the image data
let i;
let max_l = image_data_canvas.data.length;
for (i = 0; i < max_l; i += 4) {
    image_data_canvas.data[i] = 255; // R
    image_data_canvas.data[i+1] = 0; // G
    image_data_canvas.data[i+2] = 0; // B
    image_data_canvas.data[i+3] = 255; // A
}

// put the image to new canvas context
new_canvas_ctx.putImageData(image_data_canvas, 0, 0);
```

Of course I have a loop where I draw a new canvas with the old one

```
// main loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
function draw() {

    // clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw something
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    // scale
    // draw new canvas
    ctx.drawImage(new_canvas, 0,0);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

I zoom out canvas:

```
// scale viewport canvas
scale(0.5,0.5);
```

I have a mouse handler which allows me to get the coordinates of the pixel on which the mouse is hovering:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',e =>  {
    let ex = e.offsetX;
    let ey = e.offsetY;

    let exy = getXY(ex,ey);

    setTextToDOM(ex, ey, exy.x, exy.y);
})
```

I do all transformations with matrices. The problem is that I want to get the coordinates changed after the transformation but on a new canvas

Right now I'm doing it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
function getXY(mouseX,mouseY){
    let newX = mouseX * matrix[0] + mouseY * matrix[2] + matrix[4];
    let newY = mouseX * matrix[1] + mouseY * matrix[3] + matrix[5];
    return({x:newX,y:newY});
}
```

[image: problem coord]

I marked the point at which my mouse is pointed with a small orange circle. As you understood the correct answer is x: 500px and y: 500px (not 124)

All my code is here:

```js
// viewport canvas
let canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// new canvas with image_data
let new_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
new_canvas.width = 500;
new_canvas.height = 500;
let new_canvas_ctx = new_canvas.getContext('2d');
// create image_data object and fill it

let image_data_canvas = ctx.createImageData(500,500);

// fill the image data
let i;
let max_l = image_data_canvas.data.length;
for (i = 0; i < max_l; i += 4) {
    image_data_canvas.data[i] = 255; // R
    image_data_canvas.data[i+1] = 0; // G
    image_data_canvas.data[i+2] = 0; // B
    image_data_canvas.data[i+3] = 255; // A
}

// put the image to new canvas context
new_canvas_ctx.putImageData(image_data_canvas, 0, 0);


// main loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
function draw() {

    // clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw something
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    // scale
    // draw new canvas
    ctx.drawImage(new_canvas, 0,0);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

let matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];

// do the translate
// but also save the translate in the matrix
function translate(x,y){
    matrix[4] += matrix[0] * x + matrix[2] * y;
    matrix[5] += matrix[1] * x + matrix[3] * y;
    ctx.translate(x,y);
}

// do the scale
// but also save the scale in the matrix
function scale(x,y){
    matrix[0] *= x;
    matrix[1] *= x;
    matrix[2] *= y;
    matrix[3] *= y;
    ctx.scale(x,y);
}

// scale viewport canvas
scale(0.5,0.5);

// convert mouseX/mouseY coordinates
// into transformed coordinates

function getXY(mouseX,mouseY){
    let newX = mouseX * matrix[0] + mouseY * matrix[2] + matrix[4];
    let newY = mouseX * matrix[1] + mouseY * matrix[3] + matrix[5];
    return({x:newX,y:newY});
}


let px = document.getElementById('px');
let py = document.getElementById('py');
let px2 = document.getElementById('px2');
let py2 = document.getElementById('py2');


function setTextToDOM(x, y, x2, y2) {
    px.innerText = ' X:' + x + ' ';
    py.innerText = ' Y:' + y + ' ';

    px2.innerText = ' X:' + x2 + ' ';
    py2.innerText = ' Y:' + y2 + ' ';
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',e =>  {
    let ex = e.offsetX;
    let ey = e.offsetY;

    let exy = getXY(ex,ey);

    setTextToDOM(ex, ey, exy.x, exy.y);
})
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
    border: 4px solid gray;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>canvas</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <canvas id="viewport" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
    <span>
        Mouse coordinates
        <p id="px"></p>
        <p id="py"></p>
    </span>
    <span>
        Mouse coordinates after canvas change
        <p id="px2"></p>
        <p id="py2"></p>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```